# How to resolve the error when use package Alan Ai in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, alan

I'm facing an error when I use a third-party package Alan Ai and when I remove the package the project runs fine,

here's the debug console error

User-Defined Issue (Xcode): Unsupported Swift architecture
/Users/xamir/Desktop/Flutter%20Projects/AIBuddy/ai_buddy/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/alan_voice/AlanSDK.framework/Headers/AlanSDK-Swift.h:313:1
AlanSDK-Swift.h:313

Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'AlanSDK'
/Users/xamir/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/alan_voice-4.4.0/ios/Classes/AlanVoicePlugin.m:8:8

Does anyone know the issue? Could you give me a possible solution?

I need to run my project with this Package Alan Ai, but facing the above issue that I mentioned.
[image]